# How to standardize Simulink mdl file saving method in a source controlled project?

Tags: matlab, svn, tortoisesvn, simulink

I have an SVN repository in which various .mdl files are committed. Sometime, users save the .mdl files with many open tabs in the model, with various zoom setups and commit this file in the repository. I would like to know if there are any options/scripts/parameters in Simulink for saving and standardizing the file with just the main tab opened (root level), and with a normal 100% view in each of the model/library levels.

Comment: You would need to write a script which sets the ZoomFactor param and then use open_system('bdroot') to go to model root and then call save_system to save the model in that state. I do not know of any existing scripts that do these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment of @Navan, I came up with a solution, which primarily consists of looping through all subsystem blocks of a model and to execute a `set_param` command with the `ZoomFactor` param for each system level. I also found a command for removing all open subsystem tabs, in order to only have the primary root system tab that is open. Here my code, which seems to be doing exactly what I want:

```
% Making sure that the root level is open
open_system(bdroot, 'tab')
% Get all the tabs that are open, excluding the root level
tabOpened = find_system(bdroot,'LookUnderMasks','all',...
    'FollowLinks','on',...
    'Variants','AllVariants',...
    'IncludeCommented', 'on', ...
    'blocktype','SubSystem',...
    'open','on');
% Close all the unnecessary tabs tabs
cellfun(@close_system, tabOpened)

% Get a list of all the subsystem levels
blocksList = find_system(bdroot,'LookUnderMasks','all',...
    'FollowLinks','on',...
    'Variants','AllVariants',...
    'IncludeCommented', 'on', ...
    'blocktype','SubSystem');
% Set the zoom factor of each subsystem level to Normal (i.e. 100%)
for ii = 1:length(blocksList)
    set_param(blocksList{ii},'Zoomfactor','100')     
end
```